# aws lambda is not able to open file in write mode

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to open a csv file in write mode using csv writer it works file in local but when i try to do the same in aws lambda it says read only file system. I am sure that I am opening in write binary mode.

Below is the code for reference.

```
f = csv.writer(open('abc.csv','wb+'))
                f.writerow(['botName','botVersion','utteranceString','count','distinctUsers','firstUtteredDate','lastUtteredDate','status'])
```

below is the error i am getting:

```
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'abc.csv' this is exception
```

edit 1
above error is fixed by adding /tmp/ in the file path but I am not able to move csv file created in /tmp to s3 bucket
I used below code

```
s3_u.meta.client.upload_file( '/tmp/'+output_filename, 'codepipelinedev',k)
```

this is generating empty file in s3 bucket. and it is throwing an error if i test with non existing file. 
when I tried the same thing in local, csv files are created with expected data in the files. but while transfering those files I am getting empty files in our S3 bucket.

Appreciate a help in this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

AWS Lambda functions only have write access to the `/tmp` folder within the Lambda runtime environment. If you need to modify that file you need to first copy it to `/tmp` and then modify it there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Mark.I tried that too
```
s3_u.meta.client.upload_file( '/tmp/'+output_filename, bucketname,key)
```
my code is not giving any error but the files that are moved to s3 folder are with 0 bytes (they are empty)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to upload file into bucket from lambda function. And the content is same as expected. Working at my end. PFA below code.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    with open('/tmp/sample.txt','w') as fh: fh.write("First file into bucket")
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_client.upload_file(Filename='/tmp/sample.txt',Bucket='bucket-boto3- anu',Key='file1')
```